# How to implment tracking pixel on submit button with iframe

Tags: javascript

```
<iframe src="someUrl" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
```

Imagine I have iframe , by which we want to track activity on registration on our site, we want to implement it on submit button , how should I make it ? should I just add this iframe inside of submit button , or there is some other way , what I mean , see below

```
<button type="submit">
  Text
<iframe src="someUrl" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
</button>
```

Comment: I don't think a [button can contain an iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Buttons can only contain ["phrasing content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) whereas an iframe is ["interactive content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content).

Answer (score 2):

Iframes are not allowed inside buttons… but there's no reason to put one there anyway.

Tracking pixels are used to detect **when a page is loaded**.

It doesn't make sense to try to put them in any specific part of a page.

If you want to track when the form is submitted either:

- Put the tracking pixel on the page the form is submitted to
- Use a JS based tracker which responds to the click event on the button or the submit event of the form